# Can i use authorize.net payment method in indian currency?

Tags: payment-methods, currency, magento2.2.4, authorize.net

I have create 2 store INR and US Dollar.I want 2 create 2 separate payment methods store wise. Can i use authorize.net payment method in Indian currency?. I don't know which payment method use for Indian currency.Please let me suggest which one use of payment method.